# Черный экран после изменение приоритета bios legacy

Tags: bios, uefi, hp

я изменил приоритет bios boot legacy на enabled и поставил флэшку на приоритет чтоб линукс установитьрядом винда. Вот теперь ни ноутбук ни биос не включается. Выходит черный экран, даже записи нету на экране. В чем проблема? Могут ли винда слететь? Как исправить

Ноутбук марка - hp pavilion g6-2004er

Answer (score 0):

вынь батарейку из платы внутри ноута ( таблетка )
на 1-2 м